# what does option "path" mean in express res.cookie?

Tags: node.js, express

http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie

There is an option path for creating res.cookie?

What is option "path" used for? Docs say it defaults to "/"

I am trying to go session free and store username/id in client side cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies sent to clients can be set for a specific path, not just a domain.  That option sets the path.  Headers end up looking like:

```
Set-Cookie: LSID=DQAAAK…Eaem_vYg; Domain=docs.foo.com; Path=/accounts; Expires=Wed, 13 Jan 2021 22:23:01 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path

Comment: if you are using path = "/accounts", Is the cookie accessible at all other routes of the domain or just the route you specified??